# How to put and load pre-built native libraries for a wheel package using setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I'm trying to create a wheel package for my Python module that depends on native libraries. It's only for a specific Linux distribution and will not be public, it's fine and I don't want to build it using setuptools' `Extension`.

Now I have Python code and several `.so` files, and want to put them into a package so we can install it using `pip`.

So far I specified the modules in `MANIFEST.in` and call `setuptools.setup` with `include_package_data=True` so the files specified in the manifest are in the directory (3) in the tree below after I install the package under a `venv` environment.

```
venv
└── lib    <----- (1)
    └── python3.6
        └── site-packages <----- (2)
            └── my_module <----- (3)
```

My questions are:

1. There are some PyPI packages put `.so` files in (1). If it's possible I would also like to put my `.so` files there, how do I specify the file location in my `setup.py`?
2. Similarly, one of my `.so` is generated by using SWIG and it needs to be in (2). I can manually move it there but if there's a way in `setup.py` I would like to know.
3. For this case, now I need to manually specify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before executing a Python script using my code. Is there any better way to do this using setuptools?